# Python create two lists with one list comprehension

Tags: python, performance, list-comprehension

I am currently using nested for loops to add data to two lists at once. See below code.

headers, in the code below is a beautiful soup object.

```
openData = [] 
count = 0
openC = 7

closeData = [] 
closeC = 10

for j in headers:
        for z in j:
            for data in z:
                count += 1
                if count == 1:
                    openData.append(data)
                elif count == openC:
                    openData.append(data)
                    openC += 6

                if count == 4:
                    closeData.append(data)
                elif closeC == count:
                    closeData.append(data)
                    closeC += 6
```

The two lists here are openData and closeData. 
As a rough example, I know I could do something like

```
openData = [data for j in headers for z in j for data in z] 
closeData = [data for j in headers for z in j for data in z]
```

I am worried that this would take roughly twice as long since the looping operations are being carried out twice. but is there a way to combine both statements like

```
openData, closeData =  [list comprehension]
```

I am also confused about how to incorporate the if, elif logic into the list comprehension. Finally, is this something I should be doing? or would doing so be an abuse of list comprehensions. The above code I wrote works, but it looks ugly. My goal is better code than what I have.

Comment: Do you want them pointing to the same list, or two different lists?

Comment: my goal is two different lists with different data.

Comment: But the code you have listed above is identical, how are the lists supposed to be different?  It seems like the `count` logic is lost in your list comprehensions

Comment: Im appending to openData if count is 1, 7 13 etc. I'm appending to closeData if count is 4,10,16 etc. Yes thats right. I didn't include the if/elif logic in the list comprehension examples. I just gave that code as a rough example

Comment: As a general rule, if you can't figure out how to turn something into a comprehension, especially when the simpler comprehension you're starting from already barely fits on an 80-character line, the right answer is to just not use a comprehension.

Comment: Since you've tagged this "performance", presumably you're trying to do this because you know that comprehensions squeeze out about 20% of the overhead on trivial list-building loops, and you really need that 20%. But consider that anything that could build two lists at once is going to have to do something like build a list of 2-tuples to unzip, or a list of value, which-list tuples, or alternating pairs of values to slice out, or whatever. That's going to end up adding about 100% overhead to save about 20%, plus any overhead of the extra logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My attempt (with some basic initial data):

```
#some initial data
data = list(range(20))

openData, closeData = data[1::6], data[4::6]

print(openData, closeData)
```

Prints:

```
[1, 7, 13, 19] [4, 10, 16]
```

Comment: Thanks I might have been overthinking this. If I have something like      totalData = [data for j in headers for z in j for data in z]
openData, closeData = totalData[1::6], totalData[4::6] , is there a way to combine the two lines